# Deploy from SSRS -'... File can't be found..' error after report's deployment

Tags: file, reporting-services, filenames

I am experiencing the following problem:
I have deployed the same Drill-Down type report multiple times, in order to test it. (It's faster to test it deployed. And the parameters not always work correctly from the standard SSRS preview, unless you'll deploy your report)

So, at the end, when all the updates and editing were finished, I renamed my report to more appropriate name.
But, after I deployed it (had the hope it'll be my last time) - the following error appeared during the report's execution. When I drilled down from the 1st to the lower level - no data appears, but the following error:
"**The item '/Folder Name/Old Report Name' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)**"

It starts to execute when i rename it back to that "Old Report Name"
But I'd like to have the new name - for the production.

Are there anything else where this "...Old Name" remembered? 
In the report or in the SSRS properties?

I have SSMS, SSRS 2017.

Please, advice.
Thank you!

Comment: I assume you redeployed both the main report and the drill down report? It might be worth just deleting the original version from the server and redeploying both again. Some properties, such as parameter defaults, are not updated when a redeployed so it might be something like that.

Comment: I have only one report - Drill Down Chart type

Comment: This is the only one with an error